# Союз "из-за того что"

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, союзы

*Из-за того что семья парня сводит концы с концами, тот по-особенному относится к вещам и деньгам.*

Нужна ли запятая в "из-за того что"?

Answer (score 7):

***Из-за того, что** семья парня сводит концы с концами, тот по-особенному относится к вещам и деньгам.*

По общему правилу, казалось бы, союз ***из-за того, что*** разделять не нужно: придаточное предложение стоит перед главным (см. условия расчленения/нерасчленения союзов по ссылке). Но есть закономерности, наблюдаемые в литературе.

[**ПУНКТУАЦИЯ В КОНСТРУКЦИЯХ С СОСТАВНЫМИ ПОДЧИНИТЕЛЬНЫМИ СОЮЗАМИ**](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum/punctum-attach3)

> **Некоторые закономерности**
>
> **2.** Составные подчинительные союзы *благодаря тому, что... в связи с тем, что...
>
> **из-за того, что**... по причине того, что*... **расчленяются** (т. е. запятая ставится между частями союза).

Примеры из Национального корпуса русского языка:

***Из-за того, что** я боюсь постоянно обнаруживать мои провалы в памяти, я почти перестала с домашними разговаривать, стараюсь отвечать лаконично.* [Людмила Улицкая. Казус Кукоцкого]
***Из-за того, что** в похожих структурах похожие элементы могут соответствовать разным командам, необходим поиск похожих элементов.* [В. А. Овчинников. Применение генетических алгоритмов в задачах синтеза кузова автомобиля]
***Из-за того, что** мечтатель и мыслитель были в точности одного размера, начинало казаться, что это один и тот же человек в разных позах.* [Виктор Пелевин. Бэтман Аполло]

**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ** от 31.08.2023

Практика письма показывает, что в подавляющем большинстве случаев данный союз делится запятой. Но чем, интересно, он так отличается от ***вместо того чтобы, для того чтобы, ввиду того что*** и др., которые ведут себя по-разному в зависимости от структуры предложения и акцентов?
Грамота.ру отмечает закономерности в написании некоторых сложных союзов, но ведь это ещё не закон, не жёсткое правило. А также в статьях этого портала очень часто можно увидеть корректное слово «обычно».

[**ИЗ-ЗА ТОГО, ЧТО**, *союз*](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_821)

> Придаточные предложения, присоединяемые союзом «из-за того, что», выделяются (или отделяются) запятыми. При этом первая запятая **обычно** ставится не перед союзом, а между его частями (перед словом «что»).

Поэтому я думаю, что нерасчленение союза, когда нет необходимости делать ударение на его первой части, не будет являться ошибкой.

Comment: Факультативное решение.  В Нацкорпумсе союз разделяют чаще, но иногда и не разделяют: Из-за того что старшая сестра Сильва уехала в Израиль, меня вынудили уйти из газеты «Латвийский моряк». Из-за того что за ночь в горле скопилась всякая простудная дрянь, первая затяжка была какой-то тухлой, с запахом подгнившего мяса.  Трудно сказать, почему. В общем случае союз в начале предложения скорее будет не разделяться. Все должно зависеть от конкретики. Я бы не  стала делить именно это предложение на три части.

Comment: @Sharon Мне тоже не хочется делить этот союз в начале предложения. В самом деле, чем он так уж отличается от ***вместо того чтобы, для того чтобы, ввиду того что*** и др., которые ведут себя по-разному в зависимости от положения и акцентов. В ответе я отметил сведения Грамоты, апеллирующей к практике письма. Сейчас начал смотреть Нацкорпус... и бросил, так как подавляющее количество – с разделением. Спасибо, что прокомментировали – всё-таки дополню ответ.

Answer (score 0):

«Из-за того что» — запятая НЕ нужна, если это союз, то есть если можно заменить на «потому что».

Comment: Всегда ли **потому что** не разделяется запятой?

Comment: Почему если? В конкретном примере из вопроса «Из-за того что» — союз?

Comment: Александр, если *из-за того что* можно заменить на *потому что*, то запятая ставится только перед союзом. Но, если на расчленение союза влюяют другие факторы (логическое ударение, усилительная частица и т. д.) и при этом можно заменить на *потому что*, то запятая ставится только внутри союза. А если в принципе нельзя заменить, то запятая так же — только внутри.

Answer (score 0):

Запятая нужна, так как нельзя заменить на *потому что*