# Из-за того(,) что

Tags: запятые

Нужна ли запятая?

`То есть из-за того(,) что там вторая часть как бы является предложением добавочным, мы ставим запятую?`

А здесь?

`Из-за того(,) что там вторая часть как бы является предложением добавочным, мы ставим запятую?`

Comment: Может, ответ на [этот](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/460465/Союз-из-за-того-что) вопрос поможет определиться.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Да, решение факультативное [Розенталь, пункт 2](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=138#pp138). Я бы поставила запятую в таком предложении:

***То есть именно из-за тогО**, что там вторая часть как бы является предложением добавочным, мы ставим запятую?*

Здесь местоименная часть союза логически подчеркнута. А союз ***ТО ЕСТЬ*** не оказывает заметного влияния на расчленение составного подчинительного союза. А вот наличие слова **"именно"** способствует расчленению.

Таким образом, в заданных предложениях союз **можно не расчленять,** особенно в начале предложения, но расчленение тоже возможно.